# like or not like from $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which uses http get to pass on search parameters to then do an sql query.

```
Select fields:
<br>
Field 1 &nbsp
<select name="search_field1" id="search_field1">
    <option value="subject">Subject</option>
    <option value="location">Location</option>
    <option value="ref_no">Reference Number</option>
    <option value="requested_by">Requested by</option>
</select> 
&nbsp
<select id="logical_operator1" name="logical_operator1">
    <option selected value="like">contains</option>
    <option value="nlike">does not contain</option>
</select>

Search term:
<input type="text" name="search_term1" id="search_term1">
&nbsp

<select name="search_field2" id="search_field2">
    <option value="subject">Subject</option>
    <option selected value="location">Location</option>
    <option value="ref_no">Reference Number</option>
    <option value="requested_by">Requested by</option>
</select> 

&nbsp
<select id="logical_operator2" name="logical_operator2" >
    <option value="like">contains</option>
    <option value="nLike">does not contain</option>

<input type="text" name="search_term2" id="search_term2" value="">
```

on the `results.php` it grabs the parameters and then searches if a field is set to then generate the `sql` query

```
$subject = $_GET["subject"];
$location = $_GET["location"];
$ref_no = $_GET["ref_no"];
$requested_by = $_GET["requested_by"];

$sql_prefix= "select Appointment.jobID, 
                Appointment.subject, Appointment.location, Appointment.ref_no
                where";

if ( isset( $subject ) ) { 
    $sql_suffix.="`subject` like '%$subject%' ";

} else {
    $sql_suffix.="`subject` like '%' "; //set to all subjects
}

if ( isset( $location ) ) {
    $sql_suffix.= "and" . " `location` like '%$location%'";

} if ( isset( $ref_no ) ) {
    $sql_suffix.="and" . " `ref_no` like '%$ref_no%'";

} if ( isset( $requested_by ) ) {
    $sql_suffix.="and" . " `requested_by` $operator '%$requested_by%'";

}

$sql = $sql_prefix." ".$sql_suffix . " order by start asc";
```

Adding the `"not like"` parameter for the sql query has made this challenging. I need to make the query change to `"not like"` if the user selected that, but it needs to match the search term they selected. Since there can only be one of each parameter, I originally made this so it would just add the "and" plus the next term, plus `"like"`.

How can I make this sql query say either `"like"` or `"not like"` according to the user's input? Do I need some kind of loop?

Comment: The PHP code doesn't seem to match the form? You're fetching other parameters than the form contains.

Comment: I tried to compress things down to the minimum needed to show what I'm doing, it's possible that I left some stuff out from the full form

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if ($_GET) {

    $typeFields = array("subject", "location", "ref_no", "requested_by");

    $sql_prefix= "select Appointment.jobID,
     Appointment.subject, Appointment.location, Appointment.ref_no
    where";

    $sql_suffix = "";
    $flag = false;
    for ($i=1; isset($_GET["search_field".$i]); $i++) {
      for ($j=0; $j < count($typeFields); $j++) {
        if ($typeFields[$j] == $_GET["search_field".$i]) {
          $lop = "like";
          if ($_GET["logical_operator".$i] == "nLike") {
            $lop = "not like";
          }
          if ($flag) { $sql_suffix.="and"; } else { $flag = true; }
          $sql_suffix.="`".$_GET["search_field".$i]."` ".$lop." '%". $_GET["search_term".$i]."%' ";
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    $sql = $sql_prefix." ".$sql_suffix . " order by start asc";

    echo $sql."<br><br><br>";
  }
?>

Select fields:
<br>
Field 1
<form  action="/index.php" method="GET">
  <select name="search_field1" id="search_field1">
    <option value="subject">Subject</option>
    <option value="location">Location</option>
    <option value="ref_no">Reference Number</option>
    <option value="requested_by">Requested by</option>
  </select>
  <select id="logical_operator1" name="logical_operator1">
    <option selected value="like">contains</option>
    <option value="nlike">does not contain</option>
  </select>
  Search term:
  <input type="text" name="search_term1" id="search_term1">
  <select name="search_field2" id="search_field2">
    <option value="subject">Subject</option>
    <option selected value="location">Location</option>
    <option value="ref_no">Reference Number</option>
    <option value="requested_by">Requested by</option>
  </select>
  <select id="logical_operator2" name="logical_operator2" >
    <option value="like">contains</option>
    <option value="nLike">does not contain</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="search_term2" id="search_term2" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't use short open tags `<?`. Use the full version `<?php` since the short open tags are disabled by default since a bunch of versions back. A good answer also contains an explanation of what the code does. Just posting a bunch of code without any explanation isn't particularly constructive.

Comment: You missed the explanation of what your code does. You should also note that the code is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Never use user data directly in the queries like that. Use prepared statements with bound parameters instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was hoping it wouldn't need such a complicated loop but I'm not surprised that it does. I was going to ask if you could please put comments in the code so I can understand exactly what's happening